# Datenbank mit Mundart/Dialekt in Österreich

Tags: dialect

Gibt es hinsichtlich Dialekte und Mundart aus Österreich irgendwo eine zentrale Sammelstelle, ähnlich dem Duden?

Comment: Um einen Dialekt in z.B. einem Wörterbuch zu fassen, braucht man erst mal eine Schriftsprache, die die spezifischen Lautungen des Dialekts in Buchstaben wiedergibt - daran duerfte es bei den meisten deutschen Dialekten schonmal scheitern - die meisten Dialekte haben niemals eine eigene, allgemein anerkannte Transkription entwickelt (es heißt nicht umsonst "Mundart")

Comment: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de ist zum Glück nicht nur für die Bundesrepublik.  Da steht sogar *Universität Salzburg*.

Comment: @tofro: Du irrst dich. Für zahlreiche deutsche Dialekte gibt es Wörterbücher, obwohl sie keine Schriftsprachen sind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich kenne nur eine Online-Sammelstelle für Vokabeln, die in Österreich verwendet werden, das ist http://www.ostarrichi.org. Eine ähnliche Zielsetzung (auch mit ausdrücklichem Österreich-Bezug) hat die Facebook-Gruppe [Erinnerungsraum für fast ausgestorbene Worte](https://www.facebook.com/groups/184695161570864/). Diese FB-Gruppe ist aber eine geschlossene Gruppe, das heißt, man muss auf die Gnade des Administrators hoffen, wenn man aufgenommen werden will.

Für Dialekt-Wörter aus anderen Staaten sind mir leider keine Ressourcen (weder online noch auf Papier) bekannt.

---

Ich sehe aber zwei ganz prinzipielle Hindernisse, die solchen Sammlungen entgegenstehen:

### 1. Es gibt keine genormte Rechtschreibung für Dialekte

Rechtschreibregeln gelten nur für die drei standardisierten Varietäten der deutschen Sprache (deutsches Deutsch, österreichisches Deutsch, schweizerisches Deutsch), die (wahlweise einzeln oder auch gesamtheitlich) als »Hochdeutsch« oder unmissverständlicher als »Standarddeutsch« bezeichnet werden.
<sub>*(»Hochdeutsch« kann auch als Sammelbegriff für die im Süden gesprochenen Dialekte gemeint sein, als Gegensatz zu »Niederdeutsch«. Meist ist der Begriff aber als Synonym für »Standarddeutsch« gemeint.)*</sub>

Dialekte unterliegen keiner Standardisierung, daher schreibt jeder Mundartautor nach seinen ganz persönlichen Rechtschreibregeln. Das erkennt man unter anderem daran, wie der Laut [ɒ], der im Standarddeutsch nicht vorkommt, in bairischen Dialekten aber häufig den Laut [a] ersetzt, in der Schriftform wiedergegeben wird.

**Beispiel 1:**
Standarddeutsch: »ja«; Aussprache. [jaː]. Dort, wo stattdessen [jɒː] gesagt wird (z.B in Bayern) wird das Wort entweder mit o (»jo«) oder mit einem a mit Ring (»jå«) geschrieben, aber auch die Schreibweise »ja« findet man.

**Beispiel 2:**
Diphthonge werde in Dialekten oftmals (aber eben nicht immer) anders geschrieben als im Standarddeutsch. So wird z.B. das Wort »Alter«, das in Wiener Dialekt als [ˈɔɪ̯da] gesprochen wird, nicht »Euda«, sondern »Oida« geschrieben. Daneben findet man aber auch »Oita«, »Olda« oder »Olta«, weil in derselben Region auch die Aussprachevarianten [ˈɔɪ̯.tɐ], [ˈɔɫda] und [ˈɔɫ.tɐ] in Verwendung sind.

[image]
<sub>*»Oida« ist vermutlich das wichtigste Wort des Wiener Dialekts. Seine Bedeutung wird hier erklärt (auf Englisch): [How to speak Viennese using only one word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuXR53ex4iI)*</sub>

Aus diesem Grund ist unklar, mit welcher Schreibweise ein bestimmtes Wort im Wörterbuch aufgeführt werden soll.

---

### 2. Dialekte lassen sich nicht klar voneinander abgrenzen

Ein Dialektwörterbuch müsste auch angeben, zu welchem Dialekt ein Wort gehört. Das ist aber so gut wie unmöglich, weil geographisch benachbarte Dialekte sich nur schwer voneinander abgrenzen lassen.

Jemand, der z.B. sein ganzes Leben in Kiel oder Bremen verbracht hat, wird kaum einen Unterschied zwischen den Dialekten erkennen, die in Graz und Wien gesprochen werden, und wird diese beiden Dialekte vermutlich in dieselbe Schublade stecken. Ich hingegen habe die letzen 20 Jahre in Wien, und meine Kindheit und Jugend in Graz verbracht, und für mich klingen die dort gesprochenen Dialekte so unterschiedlich, wie die Dialekte von Köln und Leipzig. Das Vokabular ist teilweise unterschiedlich, gleiche Wörter werden manchmal anders ausgesprochen, und auch die Grammatik ist in einigen Details anderes.

Dagegen wäre ich wiederum nicht in der Lage, die Dialekte von Kiel und Bremen zu unterscheiden, obwohl diese beiden Städte voneinander ungefähr gleich weit entfernt sind wie Wien und Graz. (Wien - Graz: 200 km; Kiel - Bremen: 210 km)

**Beispiel:**
In Wien gehört das Wort »leiwand« (andere Schreibweisen: »leiwånd«, »leiwond«) (Bedeutung: toll, super, klasse) zum fast täglich verwendeten Vokabular, während es in Graz so gut wie gar nicht verwendet wird (es wird in Graz nicht einmal von allen verstanden). (Zitat aus dem Austropop-Hit »Schifoan« vom Wiener Wolfgang Ambros: »Schifoan ist des *Leiwandste*, wos ma si nur vuarstöön kann«)

[image]
<sub>*(»Oasch« bedeutet »schlecht, scheiße« und stammt vom Wort »Arsch« ab, während die Herkunft von »leiwand« unklar ist.)*</sub>

Gleichzeitig wird aber z.B. das Dialektwort »schiach« (für »hässlich«) in ganz Österreich und auch in Teilen von Bayern verwendet, wobei es aber auch Regionen gibt, in denen »schiach« in der Generation 70+ etwas anderes, nämlich »schüchtern« bedeutet (südliche Oststeiermark und südliches Burgenland). (»Mei Oide is a bissl schiach« kann daher je nach Region und Alter des Sprechers etwas sehr unterschiedliches bedeuten: Junger Sprecher in Fürstenfeld: »Meine Frau ist ein wenig hässlich.« Alter Sprecher n derselben Stadt: »Meine Frau ist etwas schüchtern«)

Das Beste, was man machen kann, wäre daher, für jedes Wort separat sein Verbreitungsgebiet anzugeben. Idealerweise muss auch die soziale Zugehörigkeit und das Alter der Sprecher berücksichtigt werden.

Answer (score 2):

Ja, es gibt eine «Sammelstelle» für die österreichischen Dialekte, nämlich das [Wörterbuch der bairischen Mundarten in Österreich](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%B6rterbuch_der_bairischen_Mundarten_in_%C3%96sterreich).